# window.history.pushState not going back in history

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, pushstate

I have a little problem experimenting with the history.pushstate event. I set it up so that the url of the page would be the actual URL of the page loaded via AJAX and that works just fine.

I understood that it should automaticaly create a history, loading the pages previously loaded. unfortunatly hat doesn't happen and when i click back of forward the url does change but not the page.
Can you help me? Here is my simplified code:

```
    function hijackLinks() {
        $('a').live("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            loadPage(e.target.href);    
            direction = $(this).attr('class');        
        });   
    }


    function loadPage(url) {
        if (url === undefined) {
            $('body').load('url', 'header:first,#content,footer', hijackLinks);
        } else {
            $.get(url, function (data) {
                $('body').append(data);
                 window.history.pushState(url, url, url);

                if (direction === "leftnav") {
                   //DO STUFF
                }
                if (direction !== "leftnav") {
                   //DO STUFF
                }

                setTimeout(function () {
                  //DO STUFF
                },1000);
            });
        }
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadPage(); 

    });
```

Comment: i only target safari :), initialy

Comment: I've merged the duplicate of this that you asked into this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Figured it out, I just added:

```
    window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    loadPage(location.pathname);
});
```

to the end of the page

Comment: i can't yet, only tomorrow :)

Comment: Just a tip I discovered while implementing something similar.
When handling the popstate event do not do another pushstate instead use replacestate that way you will preserver the back and forward chain for the browser.

Comment: Makes sense, why would you get other events like window load? The whole history has to be evented.

Comment: can you tell me what is loadPage(location.pathname); cuz its my problem now

Comment: @masiharastooyi i load my loadPage function using the current URL as a variable.

Comment: @Nicolo77, your comment was essential. Didn't see it in others answers, if you do, please link. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah Safari iOS has a fair few bugs with the HTML5 History API - actually, all the HTML5 browsers work differently than each other, so the functionality isn't really that standard right now.

There is [History.js](https://github.com/balupton/history.js) which solves the cross-browser compatibility problems and also provides an optional HTML4 hash fallback if you'd like.
 You can also refer to the "Notes on Compatibility" section for information on all the browser bugs that it fixes.

Answer (score 1):

I have same problem, but I fixed it. It's very easy

code example:

```
window.addEventListener("popstate", function(e) {
    window.location.href = location.href;
});
```

Comment: Works for me too