# History API and HIstory .Js issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history, history.js

I don't know if anyone will be able to see this message on time. But I can't understand history.js. I've been at it for literally two days now. For the life of me I can't just seem to make it work. My case is kind of different from all the examples I've seen online that make use of clicks to update pages. I have a drag and drop menu that changes the page based on where the draggable object was dropped. Now, the div content is updated alright. My problems begin when the url doesn't change. I've been battling with both the normal history Api as well as with history.js but all I can do is update the title and url and that's it. Popstate or statechange HAS NEVER WORKED FOR ME. I can't just seem to make the forward and backward buttons work and its killing me. I'm gradually getting to the third day and it's driving me nuts. Can someone who really understands this make it work. I am desperate at this point. My code is fairly large at this point but I'll try to recreate my code and explain as best I can.

This is my code:

```
function cursorDropped (e) {

        if (this.hitTest(aboutDrop, overlapThreshold)) {

            History.pushState(null, "About", "about.html");

            History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
                var State = History.getState();
                $('#container').load(State.url);
            })
        }
};
```

Basically a function that is called when the draggable object overlaps the circle representing the about page. So in order words, the same function that would be fired if I had a link and the about button(link) was clicked.

Comment: Welcome to SO. No need to write so much about needing help. We get that and we're here to try and help. Your question will get more quality attention if you edit all that out and stick to the bits explaining what your code should do and how it fails.

Comment: Thanks. Will do that now.

Comment: @DelightedD0D it seems you're using the normal history API, you will notice that I'm using capital H which is the history.js polyfill. However, i tried your method using the normal api and still the forward and backward button worked but the page content wasn't updating. I think just using the console on a random page doesn't fully put to perspective as when you're actually developing.

Comment: Yeah, I misunderstood at first. It seems neither history.js nor the native history api really do what we expect, ie, they allow you to update the urls in the history list but dont automatically store and retrieve the actual page content resulting in the back button just flipping through the urls, not the actual pages. For that, you'll need a bit more handling on your end, see http://blog.cergis.com/posts/11/html5-history-api

Comment: Or for a simpler solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/5398511/1376624

Comment: @DelightedD0D Will check those out now. What baffles me is how these tutorials online just seem to make everything click and yet when I follow those, nothing seems to work.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the tutorial you used? I'd bet we'll find they've done something similar and just didnt point it out.

Comment: Oh wow. I used lots and lots of tutorials, because no one really worked for me so I just kept on jumping from one tutorial to another. But I think the basic concepts still remain the same. Here are some of them,

Comment: https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/lovely-smooth-page-transitions-with-the-history-web-api--cms-26405

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/rethinking-dynamic-page-replacing-content/

Comment: On the first one, scroll down to the "Content" section, they are using the `History.Adapter.bind( window, "statechange", function()` handler to get the html from the new page and load it in the div

Comment: On the second one, the author states *"After changing the URL, we'll want to set up a function to load the content - loadContent() seems like a good name....."* and has a section titled *"Handle browser back and forward button clicks"*. Looks like both of those are showing solutions similar the the ones linked to above.

Comment: Yeah I tried both of those already. Didn't work. I don't know if my problems seem to stem from the fact that I'm not using links but rather drag and drop. Do you think so?

Comment: Shouldnt be, but it's hard to say without seeing the code. Is there any way you can make a jsfiddle with a simplified version of your drag and drop and the code you tried? Or a link to a page if you have it live somewhere

Comment: I'm using the greensock drag and drop plugin. Don't know how possible it will be to load it in jsfiddle

Comment: This should get you started https://jsfiddle.net/vgLcndpf/84/

Comment: Would it be ok if I put my project on github so that way you have access to all the files. There are too many things I need to do that I can't seem to figure out using js fiddle.

Comment: Sure that would be ok

Comment: OK. I'm gonna upload it now and send the link.

Comment: Here is the link to the project containing all files and plugins. I'm really looking forward to your corrections as well as criticisms. --- https://github.com/Seimodei/kingsleytv

Comment: Please see this pull request on your repo. It should address all your issues. https://github.com/Seimodei/kingsleytv/pull/1

Comment: Thank you a million. It works just like I want it to. Quick question before I let you go, what did you think of the project so far. I mean like the menu concept and all.

Comment: Honestly, I think it looks neat. Artistically, I like the concept. That said, Im a bit skeptical of how user friendly it would be. Some might not understand what to do with the menu and you might run into compatibility issues with some touch devices. Another drawback is that the svgs and animations are not responsive (they dont resize with the window). This means that you'll need additional logic to draw the elements differently or render a different menu if you intend  support mobile devices

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and everything. And yeah, you're right. I  only intend to use this menu up to a certain width after which a new menu is rendered. Once again thanks for your help. It helped immensely.

Comment: I just encountered a little issue where the back and forward buttons only change the URL and not the page content when I refresh the about page. What do you reckon is the problem?

Comment: This is happening because when you refresh the browser, the browser navigates to the actual about.html file rather than getting the content via ajax. The problem with that is that about.html doesnt include index.js which has the statechange listener in it therefore, it never gets called to load the page. See https://github.com/Seimodei/kingsleytv/pull/2 for a possible fix, which is to make sure that each file has the resources needed for all the pages. ie, include index.js in all pages.

Comment: A better way to solve this issue would be to have index.html, include all your js for all pages. Make your urls like `http://thesite.com/index?page=about.html`, then use the `page` GET parameter to determine which page content to load.

Comment: It works as it should now. One more question, I'm confused as to where to apply the page transition.  I can only transition out,  when the about page loads, the background still remains white. I don't know where exactly to put the code for transitioning in. I tried putting it as a callback to the .get request but still it doesn't work.

Comment: @DelightedD0D I don't know how else to reach you except through this comment section. It's about the last code you helped me with. When I upload my website to an online server, it does not seem to load the index.html page first. It just goes blank. However, if I add a /index.html to the url, everything works. It seems to be from the page setup in the javascript you helped with. Please, could you help me with the line of code that helps me resolve this. I've tried a lot of things from .htaccess to using an index.php but none of those seem to work. I need your assistance. Thanks.